# I'm bad at doing this, I don't know how to put it into words. Can you help me find what to say?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> So I've been gone for a while, it's been days,
> Of course, I'm on holiday, a new phase,
>
> Really, it couldn't be avoided, it's true,
> Run ragged by  my work, my body was through.
>
> Yet, despite all of that, what I'm trying to say,
> Is that I missed Puzzling SE, and I'm here to stay.

What am I trying to do?

Comment: Who do you want to say it to? ;)

Comment: I'm saying to everyone here at PSE, in regards to my absence last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's

> You are trying to apologize and say sorry, since that's the first letter of each line. (Excluding the last line).

Comment: This is the along the right lines of what I'm trying to say, but the true answer is an action, would you phrase your answer as such?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Ahh, okay, here we go :)

Comment: That is correct! Good job.